# hard inequality with exponential

Tags: inequality

If $c > b > a > 0$, how can I prove that $ \sum_{cyclic}^{} (e^{a-b}+e^{b-a}) \ge 2a-2c +3+ \sum_{cyclic}^{} (\frac {b}{a})^{\sqrt{ab}}$

Comment: You are currently dividing by $0$.

Comment: Have you tried differentiating and using optimisation under constraints?

Comment: I don't know how to start (you are right, I edited my question)

Comment: You want to prove that the minimum of a certain function is non-negative, now the minimum of a smooth function of several variables has to be either at a critical value (hence you need partial derivatives) or at the boundary of the domain.

Comment: What does the index "cylic" mean int this case?  And and b are constants.

Comment: The cyclic sum is simply the sum obtained by permuting the letters cyclical, i.e. moving the first letter to last.

Comment: I rolllback your edition. Not only you have completely changed the question, the new inequality you were asking is false. If you have a different question, ask a new one.